# IntelliJ plugins lost (after upgrade to 2023.2.1): How to find out previous plugins installed?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, upgrade, recovery

After upgrading to IntelliJ 2023.2.1 all my plugins, extensions and settings have been lost. As this version caused other problems (like constant scanning and indexing) I downgraded to 2023.1.5 but same here, all plugins gone. I am on Linux and I did not change or delete anything in the `~/.config` folder. How can I recover my old plugins (and settings)?

Did quite some Google research on this but no solution really helped. I have quite some old settings in `~/.config/JetBrains` from previous versions, so essentially I would be happy if I can at least retrieve the list of plugins I had installed. Can I retrieve it from there?

Will accept any answer which at least helps me to find out which plugins I had installed, because I can not remember all of them. There is e.g. a file bundled_plugins.txt in the config folder, but it does not contain what I need

Was not aware of the SettingsSync option, will turn that on in the future.

Comment: Do you have logs folder from previous version?